# Github website has no formatting after deployment despite working fine on deployment

Tags: github, web, deployment, jekyll, config

So I tried deploying my github website portfolio, after hosting it locally. All the tabs are working, formatting is fine too. The template used was al folio after forking. However after deployment, all formatting of the webpage is gone. None of the tabs are working - giving me 404 errors. Please help!!

[Hosting it locally this is how the website looked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiH9C.jpg)

[This is how the website looked after deploying it!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0XHM.jpg)

I thought the deployment would be exactly as the local server hosting. I tried even changing the deployment branch to source and master and tried.

Comment: I voted to close this question because is about debugging a problem but has no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  There is no way to help you from the limited information you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Open the github produced website and check in DevTools where are your css files.